# How to get xpath of drop down on the basis of enable/visiblity?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Basically, I'm having multiple drop on a single page. If I click on edit icon, drop down gets enable.Now again if I click on other drop down, the first drop down gets disable and second drop down gets enable.
I'm trying to find the xpath by visibilty of drop down. Like my xpath is common for all drop down but it should select the values on the basis of enable drop down visiblity.

HTML for disabled:

```
<select class="tabledit-input form-control fc-alt" style="display: none;" name="idLoc" disabled="">
```

HTML for enabled:

```
<select class="tabledit-input form-control fc-alt" style="" name="idLoc">
```

Mycode which I tried:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("my_xpath']")));
```

Each time, my xpath is selecting the 1st drop(which is disable) but if I find it by visibility, it will find the drop down values which is enable and I will be having my problem solved.

Please let me know in case of clarification.

Comment: shared the HTML code of both enable and disable element

Comment: have you try :-        //select[@class='tabledit-input form-control fc-alt' and @style='' and @name='idLoc']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use below `XPath`:

```
//select[@style='display: block;']
```

to match *visible* `select`. Or

```
//select[@style='display: none;']
```

to match *invisible*

But as both elements present in DOM you'd better just to use correct expected condition which is `visibilityOfElementLocated` in this case:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("my_xpath'")));
```

Above code should allow you to get `select` element that is currently visible

If element has `disabled` attribute, you can fetch disabled `select` with

```
//select[@disabled]
```

and enabled

```
//select[not(@disabled)]
```

Comment: Did I miss something? :) any comments from downvoter?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but when I'm hitting ```//select[@class='tabledit-input form-control fc-alt'][@name='idLoc'][@style='display:block;']``` it is not highlighting. But it should highlight as the code implies for enable drop down as ```<select class="tabledit-input form-control fc-alt" style="display: block;" name="idLoc">```

Comment: @Saad, note that there is a space between `display:` and `block;` and so you should use `[@style='display: block;']` instead of `[@style='display:block;']`. This seem to be small detail but it does matter

Comment: Thanks for correction. Currently, issue I'm facing is that it is highlighting 2 drop down in one page. 1st html which is disabled is - ```<select class="tabledit-input form-control fc-alt" style="display: none;" name="idLoc" disabled="">``` and 2nd htmlwhich I want to select the values from is this- ```<select class="tabledit-input form-control fc-alt" style="" name="idLoc">``` Anything for not selecting the 1st html by excluding ```disabled``` option.

Comment: Try `//select[not(@disabled)]`